# ftp server dont get curectly user on nodejs

Tags: node.js, ftp

So, I have nodejs ftp server on ftp-srv and when it gets username and password on json I cant connect to ftpserver. I think, reboot ftp sever  can help to solve it.

But Maybe there is another way to solve it.I tried to do function "fa" and return ftpServer.on(Ftp server gets username and password) and then use setinterval() and reboot it.But It doesnt work.

This is ftp server.

````
const port = 21;
const ftpServer = new FtpSrv({
    url: "ftp://0.0.0.0:" + port,
    anonymous: true
});
setInterval(fa,1)
function fa() {

    return ftpServer.on('login', ({ connection, username, password }, resolve, reject) => {
        if (username === 'data["username"]' && password === 'Xserewer'){
            return resolve({ root: "/home/" });
        }
        return reject(new errors.GeneralError('Invalid username or password', 401));
    });
    

}
ftpServer.listen().then(() => {
    console.log('Ftp server is starting...')
})```
````